# Node js instalation error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When i try installing node js it gives me this errors

```
C:\Users\Administrator>cd C:/xampp/htdocs/chat
C:\xampp\htdocs\chat>npm install

npm WARN package.json chat@4.5.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json chat@4.5.0 No README data
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\ node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! enoent getaddrinfo ENOENT registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! C:\xampp\htdocs\chat\npm-debug.log
```

My question is how can i prevent those errors and install node js and socket io correctly.

Comment: you can ignore those warnings i believe

Comment: No i can not ignore them. It doesn't install me node js if i ignore them

Comment: Those errors are generated by NPM - specifically your call `npm install`, which implies you already have NodeJS installed.

Comment: I think that you can install Node js directly from terminal. But if you use Windows, then the best solution is to download the Windows installer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you install from [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

after that. just do nvm install 
to check. node -v inside your terminal

Answer (score 0):

Install NodeJS from their website, then execute `npm init` within your project folder.

Afther that you can install dependencies from NPM.

Just read, what's on their websites under "getting started"...

Answer (score 0):

I did npm init and this is my .json file

```
  "name": "chat",
  "version": "4.5.0",
  "description": "IO",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Dan  Vasii",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies":
         {
                  "socket.io" : "*",
                  "express" : "*"
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the Windows installer from https://nodejs.org/en/ .

Run the installer (the .msi file you downloaded in the previous step.)

Follow the prompts in the installer (Accept the license agreement, click the NEXT button a bunch of times and accept the default installation settings).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for the above error.

1. Go to ([nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/)) and Download NodeJs.
2. Install the **NodeJs** where you want in your PC
3. Now try to execute the command **npm install**

The error will be resolved. Any help needed please refer to this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/)